# Eureka Server dashboard is not coming up with JDK 11

Tags: java

After migrating to java 11, Eureka Server dashboard is not coming up.
The same is running with jdk 1.8.
When the server is started as spring boot application, the server is started successfully but when tried to launch it from browser it is throwing 404 error.

This is the error I am getting :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 404

Comment: What is the exception in the stacktrace on the start up of the server?

Comment: There is no exception on the start up of the server. Server is successfully started.